# How to convert a snake_case JSON to nested JSON in java?

Tags: java, json

I have few cases where I want to convert a snake_case JSON to nested JSON 
e.g.

```
{
    "snake_case": {
        "test": "value"
    }
}
```

to

```
{
    "snake": {
        "case": {
            "test": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in java other then manually parsing the strings with `_` or there any libraries are there in java?

Comment: Write the code.  You can do it ad-hoc, knowing each "snake_case" (interesting term) key you want converted, or as a general routine that will convert all of them.  For the general case you'd need to put "snake_case" and "snake_skin" in the same outer object, requiring some thought.

Comment: Agreed. Write code and paste it back if you need help with it. I recommend using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) as it will parse the json into a map of maps, so it will be a lot easier to modify it in place and handle the case mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your JSON data as String:

```
String strjson="{snake_case: {test: value}}";
```

then

```
JSONObject jj=new JSONObject(strjson);
JSONObject jfinal=new JSONObject();

Iterator<String> itr=jj.keys();

while(itr.hasNext())
{
    String key=itr.next();
    if(key.contains("-"))
    {
        JSONObject jkey=jj.getJSONObject(key);
        JSONObject jnew=new JSONObject();
        jnew.put(key.split("-")[1],jkey);
        jfinal.put(key.split("-")[0],jnew);
    }
}
```

you can get the output in jfinal.

Comment: Is that a dash or an underscore? And how about handling the two keys "snake_case" and "snake_blah" by putting both "case" and "blah" in the same nested object?

Comment: Also I suggest using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to parse the json into a map of maps. Then it will be easy to modify those same maps to do what the OP asks.

Answer (score 0):

You could BSON to achieve this.  Here is the code you would use.

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
 //import org.bson.Document;

 //Declare three json object
 Document root= new Document();
 Document rootSnake = new Document();
 Document rootSnakeCase = new Document();


 //Add value to the most nested object
 rootSnakeCase.append("test","value");



 //combine the objects together
 if (!rootSnakeCase.isEmpty()){
 rootSnake.append("case",rootSnakeCase);
 }
 if (!rootSnake.isEmpty()){
 root.append("snake",rootSnake);
 }


 //output code
 System.out.println(root.toJson());
```